# Skip Downloading a File In Powershell Based on Content Disposition Header

Tags: powershell, web

I'm trying to skip downloading files that I already have, and I want to determine if I already have them based on the 'Content Disposition' header.  Is there a simple way to do this in Powershell?

For some instances I was able to send a 'HEAD' request before the 'GET' so I could get the file name, but I discovered that's not reliable, and really need to read the headers of the 'GET' to determine if I want to save the content of that same 'GET'

```
$headResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $url -WebSession $Session -Method Head

$headResponse.Headers['Content-Disposition'] -match 'filename="(.*)"'
$fileName = $Matches[1]

if((Test-Path $fileName -PathType Leaf) -eq $false){
    Invoke-WebRequest $url -WebSession $Session -OutFile $fileName -Method Get
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no way to do this with Powershell, so resorted to using .NET which isn't so friendly, but got the job done.  Here's what I came up with:

```
try {
    $response = $request.GetResponse()

    $contentDisposition = $response.Headers['Content-Disposition']

    $fileName = '';

    if($contentDisposition -ne $null){
        $contentDisposition -match 'filename="(.*)"'
        $fileName = $Matches[1]
    } else {
        $uri = [Uri]$_
        $fileName = $uri.Segments | Select-Object -Last 1
    }

    if((Test-Path $fileName -PathType Leaf) -eq $false) {
        $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
        $bufferSize = 1024

        $buffer = new-object byte[] $bufferSize

        $bytesRead = 0;

        try {
            # Read from response and write to file
            $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create([System.IO.Path]::Combine($currentFilePath, $fileName));
            while (($bytesRead = $responseStream.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize)) -ne 0) 
            {
                $fileStream.Write($buffer, 0, $bytesRead);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if($fileStream -ne $null){
                $fileStream.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}
finally {
    if($response -ne $null){
        $response.Dispose()
    }
}
```